# Why Visual C++ compiler compiles unused classes into executable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I  probably misunderstand how the compilers work,but I have the following situation.I have a VC++ 2012 project.The project contains an API with hundreds of classes.Now, I create 'main' entry point file where I just use some  std stuff.The main doesn't include even a single header from the API.Yet when I compile I see that pretty everything from the API is getting compiled into the executable?Why does it happen?Is it something I should configure in the project properties?

Comment: If those files are part of the project they also get compiled in

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: ask the compiler to optimize if you want it to optimize

Comment: Without details, it's hard to say exactly what is going on. Try and narrow it down a bit for us.

Answer (score 1):

Source files that are part of the project are compiled also if "unused" through headers and references from your main routine.

If you don't want those compiled simply remove them from the project. The compiler might be able to optimize everything away but that doesn't mean they're not compiled if part of the project first.

Comment: But I said,there are no references/headers of those files in the main.

Comment: Doesn't matter, they're source files part of the project and they are also compiled. Why do you want those in the project in the first place if you don't use them? Are you trying to export those symbols?

Comment: as Marco A. said: If you linked a `*.cpp` file in the `Project Explorer` it will be compiled. Another solution can be right click / Properties check "Exclude" property for a specific file in PE